# What is the official/correct orthography for Alsatian / Elsässisch German?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, orthography, writing-systems, german

As per the Wikipedia article on the Alsatian language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsatian_dialect#Orthography) the orthography
includes the latin letters A,B,C ... X,Y,Z and the following vowels with diacritics with the corresponding IPA below.

| Orthography | Ä | À | É | Ö | Ü | Ù |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPA | /ɛ/ | /ɑ/,/ɑː/ | /ɛ/ | /œ/ | /y/ | /u/ |

But as per the "Office pour la langue et le cultures d'alsace et de moselle" (http://www.olcalsace.org/) the official(?) body within France for language and culture for the Alsace region.
The orthography for Alsatian (all/most dialects) follow the ORTHAL system (http://www.orthal.fr/index.html & https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthal)

Latest specification (http://www.orthal.fr/ORTHAL_2016.pdf) & Explanatory document (http://www.olcalsace.org/sites/default/files/documents/synthese_ORTHAL.pdf).

Notably the differences are - the letters X & Y are not a part of the alphabet with the digraph KS & letter J replacing them in ORTHAL.

The vowels are indicated by the following different set of letters. With umlauted letters following standard German orthography/phonology for the most part.
Vowels with the grave accent indicating changes from standard German orthography/phonology.

Presumably to allow for better readability/etymological link with standard German.
Their publications E.g. - glossaries for children - http://www.olcalsace.org/fr/lexiques exemplifies the use of this orthography.

| Orthography | Ä | À | Ë | Ì | Ö | Ü | Ù |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPA | /ɛ/ | /ɑ ~ ɒ/ | /æ/ | /ɪ/ | /œ/ | /y/ | /u/ |

It seems that either the Wikipedia article is wrong or outdated.
I can update Wikipedia, but before I update the article, I wanted to find out if there is an authoritative source for the orthography besides olcalsace.

Comment: It seems that you already found the most standard orthography with ORTHAL. Which does not mean that you may encounter a wider variety of orthographies while researching dialect publications from Alsace.

Comment: See https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elsässisch#Verschìedena_Schrìftàrta

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer - Thanks for the link, so which one is the official Orthography? The one in the English Wikipedia page for Alsatian or the ORTHAL listed above?

Comment: *Dia Methoda hàt zìmlig Erfolg, zum Beispil ìn da régionàla elsassischa Blättla (Zittung "L'ALSACE", "Haut-Rhin Magazine") oder uff zweisprochiga Schìlder wia ìm Elsassischa Ecomusée oder àm Nèiweiher-Stàuidàmm. S OLCA, s elsassischa Sprochàmt, hàt sa aui ààgnumma.*

Comment: It sounds like it's sort of expanding but that implies another one is still in use.  Probably the article should include both orthographies.

Comment: Do you know if the letters - Ë & Ù are present in Orthal. Looks like Ì is included for sure.
The PDF indicates they exist but the Ë & Ù don't show up commonly in most text including the Alsatian Wikipedia.